# Civil prosecution for motoring offences in the UK

Tags: civil-judgment

If an there's evidence (e.g. video footage) of a motoring offense being committed, such as speeding, dangerous driving, and the CPS haven't prosecuted, is it possible to make a civil prosecution.

Thanks

Comment: A civil prosecution is something of an oxymoron; what you are thinking of is a private prosecution.

Comment: ah, exactly, thanks!